# Block specific C range of IP addresses

Tags: htaccess, apache, ip-address, block

I can't find a good reference though my understanding is that ranges in an IPv4 address are:

a.b.c.d

I wish to block only the C ranges starting with 51.15.51.0 and ending with 51.15.142.255.

I have tried things like `Deny for 51.15.51/142` in the past (the `/` operator only seems to work for the d range) so this breaks the entire website with an HTTP 500 server error.

Additionally if I use `Deny from 51.15` it would block ranges below c-51 and above c-142 which I don't want to do.

How do I efficiently block 51.15.51.0 through 51.15.142.255 in the `htaccess` file?

Comment: There is a better link but on a different site [How to Block an IP address range using the .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483068/how-to-block-an-ip-address-range-using-the-htaccess-file)

Comment: @RohitGupta The Webmasters question is a "better" reference IMO (both answers). It gives all the up-to-date information/tools to answer this question. The SO question does not and is arguably out of date.

Comment: "so this breaks the entire website with an HTTP 500 server error" - And you are using `for` instead of `from` (but maybe that's just a typo). However, `Deny` is also deprecated on Apache 2.4 and moved to mod_access_compat (an extension not installed by default). This is also mentioned in the [linked question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/125100/block-ip-range-using-htaccess).

Comment: Also, don't necessarily discount regex. The IP range 51.15.51.0 to 51.15.142.255 isn't "too bad" to convert to regex (since it's just one octet that varies). eg. `^51\.15\.(5[1-9]|[6-9]\d|1[0-3]\d|14[012])\.`